# Using Array submission syntax in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Well, I have a lot of input fields in a form, some of them are like this:

```
<input name="agents[]" type="file" />
```

Moreover suppose there is a plus button besides this field like this:

```
<img src="plus.jpg" id="some_id" />
```

A user can add more agents field in addition to the one field present already.

So I was wondering how would I handle these kind of input fields when submitting form data through Ajax? Using JavaScript objects perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

What's the main problem?
For Ajax uploading i'm using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
For handling dinamic form contents i use jquery .serialize()
Like this

```
        var info = $("#additem").serialize();       
        $.post('/url.php', info, function(data) {       
          // response
          }, 'json');
```

"additem" is the id of the form

```
       <form id="additem">
```